# onClickListener not working within Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

When I click the button in one of my fragments, nothing happens, the listener is not working. Whenever I type button to try to cast to a button, it doesn't turn purple as it should.

**Java:**

```
public class CollegeMatch extends Fragment {
    TextView resuLTS;
    EditText actorsat;
    EditText rank;
    EditText gpa;
    EditText apclasses;
    public Button calcButton;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_college_match, container, false);    

        resuLTS = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.resuLTS);
        actorsat = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.actorsat);
        gpa = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.gpa);
        rank = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.rank);
        apclasses = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.apclasses);
        Button calcButton;
        calcButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.calcButton);
        calcButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view2) {
                float act = Float.parseFloat(actorsat.getText().toString());
                float ap = Float.parseFloat(apclasses.getText().toString());
                float rk = Float.parseFloat(rank.getText().toString());
                float gp = Float.parseFloat(gpa.getText().toString());
                float res = act + ap + rk + gp;
                resuLTS.setText(Float.toString(res));    
            }    
        });
        return view;
    }    
}
```

**XML:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="layout.CollegeMatch"
        android:background="#bdeaf4"
        android:id="@+id/calcBTN">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Find colleges!"
        android:id="@+id/textView134"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="37dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/actorsat"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:hint="Enter  Composite Score "
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView134"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/gpa"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/gpa" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ACT  Composite"
        android:id="@+id/textView135"
        android:textColor="@color/abc_input_method_navigation_guard"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/actorsat"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="46dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="46dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Unweighted GPA"
        android:id="@+id/textView136"
        android:textColor="@color/abc_input_method_navigation_guard"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView135"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView135"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView135" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Class Rank (Top _ %)"
        android:id="@+id/textView138"
        android:textColor="@color/abc_input_method_navigation_guard"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView136"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView136"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView136" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/rank"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tex554"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/apclasses"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/apclasses"
        android:hint="Enter Here  (omit % sign) " />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Total # of AP classes"
        android:id="@+id/tex554"
        android:textColor="@color/abc_input_method_navigation_guard"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView138"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView138"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView138" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/apclasses"
        android:hint="Enter number here"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tex554"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Match Me!"
        android:id="@+id/calcButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/apclasses"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView134"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView134" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your College Match Results:"
        android:id="@+id/textView155"
        android:textColor="@color/abc_input_method_navigation_guard"
        android:textSize="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold|italic"
        android:layout_below="@+id/calcButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/gpa"
        android:hint="Enter GPA here"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView138"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rank"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/rank" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:id="@+id/resuLTS"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView155"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView155"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView155"
        android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView155"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView155"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please add Button xml

Answer (score 1):

You are doing stuff inside the `onViewCreated()` method. This method is fired after the `view` is created so it doesn't apply your stuffs.

Move the code inside the `onCreateView()` like below:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_college_match, container, false);

    //do stuffs, for example:

    resuLTS = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.resuLTS);
    actorsat = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.actorsat);
    gpa = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.gpa);
    rank = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.rank);
    apclasses = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.apclasses);

    Button calcbutton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.calcbutton);
    calcbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View view2) {
            float act = Float.parseFloat(actorsat.getText().toString());
            float ap = Float.parseFloat(apclasses.getText().toString());
            float rk = Float.parseFloat(rank.getText().toString());
            float gp = Float.parseFloat(gpa.getText().toString());
            float res = act + ap +rk +gp;
            resuLTS.setText(Float.toString(res));

        }

    });
    return view;
}
```

That should work (I'm out of compiler so this might not be perfect, for any question I'm here)

Comment: Thankyou for the response, however this still does not work, whenever i click the button nothing happens whatsoever, i don't even hear a click.

Comment: @MichaelBecker uhm, have you tried debugging to see if the onClick is reached?

Comment: Onclick is never reached

Comment: @MichaelBecker i've seen you accepted, the problem is solved?

Comment: no it still does nothing. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong

Comment: @MichaelBecker ok, looks like this is the premade code from Android studio. remove all code you are not currently using from the java. The params, the onCreate (no need to override), the attach, the viewCreated(), the "onButtonPressed", the newIstance and the listener

Comment: I did that. I got rid of everything, and still no click

Comment: @MichaelBecker uhm ok. you set the breakpoint inside the first line of the onlclick right? then It's really unusual. try posting the updated java file and the full xml doc. There might be some error in names or links

Comment: Put a toast inside onClick and check. I don't see any problem with your code.

Comment: @MichaelBecker tools:context="layout.CollegeMatch" in your layout. check if this is correct. it should be the full namespace. is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

**I always see this mistake**

I've made this mistake myself and seen other people do it, when inflating your layout do this:

```
RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_college_match, null);
```

Afterwards you can do this:

```
Button calcButton = (Button) view.getChildAt(8);
```

I'm not sure if you can still call `view.findViewById()` this way but it would be a good idea trying.

I this does not work and you get an error be sure to post it.

**UPDATE:**

I have reread the inflate method and you should be able to use your way as long as the last parameter of inflater.inflate is true, but it is not recommended to do so.

**FINAL ANSWER:**

In your XML you are adding the id textView134 more than once:

At first textview:

```
android:id="@+id/textView134"
```

At button:

```
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView134"
```

At the button align left your **ADDING** a new id, instead do this:

```
android:layout_alignLeft="@id/textView134"
```

Notice that there is no "+" when referencing to an existing id.

I've also found it in quite a few other views so be sure to fix that.

Why your problem is occurring?
When adding a new id to (nothing? I guess) the code isn't using the id from the edittexts. Be sure to know the difference between adding and referencing ids.

**Hope I helped,**

**-Daniel**

Comment: Thankyou for your help, but still no luck :( . I'm at a loss, I've tried everything. I get no errors but it just does nothing when I click the send button.

Comment: What does it need to do exactly?

Comment: It is supposed to add up numbers entered into text fields when the user hits the send button

Comment: I have updated my answer, be sure to look at the Final answer as that will more than likely fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

You only have to get the view of activity that carry this fragment and this could only happen when your fragment is already created

override the `onViewCreated()` method inside your fragment and enjoy its magic :) ..

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.YOURBUTTONID);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
     //place your action here
     }
});
```

Hope this could help you ;